# Real-World QVT

Tags: eclipse, mda

QVT (Query View Transformation) is a OMG specification of a Model-to-Model transformation language. Some tools already implement it (Eclipse, androMDA). I'm wondering whether it is really used in real-world cases. Will it ever take off and be used to tackle real-world problems? Is anybody using the QVT language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like QVT is beeing used for Model Driven Security applications. It is a good choice because of clearly defined semantics and provability. This still is reasearch however. France Telecom is experimenting with QVT. They want to use it for database migrations and a generative approach for applications.

http://smartqvt.elibel.tm.fr/events/QVT%20Experimentations%20at%20France%20Telecom.pdf
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=4159881

Answer (score 3):

From observing the MDD community for our own projects, I'd guess that QVT will eventually pick up. Currently ATL and Kermeta seem to be very popular, and from looking at the postings in the groups not only in academia.

There's an implementation of Declarative QVT now (see the M2M Eclipse group for the announcement), that'll be very interesting for us. We've been using the ModelMorf prototype, but it was a prototype and had a very huge turnaround time. I hope that with the integration of dQVT into the Eclipse tool chain we'll be able to use it for our own projects (a SoftEng tool, see http://rcos.iist.unu.edu, sorry, academic of course :).

I guess the pain of doing Model-driven development by hand/with man-power is not high enough yet...once the tools really increase the order of magnitude of productivity, that'll change.